# Bind localStorage variable to element on pageload

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want to bind (attach, maybe?) a variable stored in localStorage to an element (e.g. `<p>`, `<span>`, or maybe `<div>`) on page load and if the variable is not set, display a default value.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know how to grab the localStorage variable, I'd do the following:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var lsVar = /*do your magic here (i.e. check for localstorage and grab the data or null*/;
    var myDiv = document.getElementByWhatever(); // Id?

    // if lsVar is undefined, null, 0, false or empty string, set your default value
    lsVar = lsVar || "My default value";
    myDiv.innerHTML = lsVar; // or text?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
(function () {
    var MY_VALUE_DEFAULT = 'MY_VALUE_DEFAULT',
        myValue = localStorage.getItem('myValue') || MY_VALUE_DEFAULT;

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (e) {
        var myDisplayElement = document.getElementById('displayElement');
        myDisplayElement.innerText = myValue;
    });
}());
```